# 'java.io.ObjectOutputStream' is deprecated - an error in Intellij IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea, deprecated, objectoutputstream

I have this code:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.util.Date;

public class EmployeeProcessor {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Employee employee = new Employee();
        employee.lastName = "Smith";
        employee.firstName = "Adam";
        employee.id = 123456789;
        employee.salary = 50000;

        try(FileOutputStream fileOutStr = new FileOutputStream("Employee.ser");
            ObjectOutputStream objectOutStr = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOutStr)) {

            objectOutStr.writeObject(employee);
            System.out.println("An employee is externalized into the file Employee.ser");

        } catch (IOException ioError){
            ioError.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

But in Intellij IDEA `ObjectOutputStream` class is strikethrough Like this:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q2rze.png). When pointing mouse pointer over - this message appears: `'java.io.ObjectOutputStream' is deprecated`. What does it mean?

When I run this code, IntelliJ opens "Edit Configurations" windows asking me to introduce VM options. But I leave it blank and run anyway.

Comment: If somethings deprecated, it means it's obsolete/dangerous to use. A quick search though shows that while that class contains deprecated methods, the class itself doesn't appear to be deprecated. This might be a IntelliJ bug.

Comment: List of deprecated items in Java 8: [Deprecated list](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/deprecated-list.html)

Comment: @Vusal, thank you for the link. But class `ObjectOutputStream` not in this list.

Comment: Yes. I found only `java.io.ObjectOutputStream.PutField.write(ObjectOutput)` as deprecated.

Comment: `java.io.ObjectOutputStream` is *not* deprecated, and any tool that says otherwise is lying to you.

Answer (score 2):

IntelliJ IDEA has an intention action to annotate library classes as Deprecated using the [External Annotations](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/external-annotations.html) support. You've probably triggered this intention action by accident.

[image: annotate]

For the classes deprecated this way there supposed to be the reverse action: Deannotate, but it may not work ([bug reported](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-174522)).

To fix it manually, find the `annotations.xml` file in a directory that is configured in the [SDK Annotations tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W8DGF.png) and edit/remove it.

**UPDATE**: Deannoate action should work now, but only while inside the annotated class itself, not from its reference.