# Why idea highlights @JsonIgnore annotation as deprecated?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jackson, deprecated

It looks like:

[image]

I use import statement:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
```

jackson version: 2.9.0

I tried to inspect source code of annotation and I don't see `@Deprecated` annotation there.

Could anyone explain it?

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/a/44569788/104891 help?

Comment: @CrazyCoder I can't find annotations.xml file in idea folder and I don't have configured path in annotation tab of JDK

Comment: Alt+Enter, Deannotate in `JsonIgnore` class.

Comment: @CrazyCoder, http://dl3.joxi.net/drive/2018/12/12/0005/3037/338909/09/1095eef216.jpg

Comment: @CrazyCoder, If I click alt+enter on JsonIgnore  class source  it doesn't show menu

Comment: Inside `JsonIgnore` class, not on the usage.

Comment: @CrazyCoder, read previous comment)

Comment: [Works for me](https://i.imgur.com/xO9X8aE.png) in the decompiled class.

Comment: @CrazyCoder happy you))

Comment: Annotations may be [attached to the library](https://i.imgur.com/eQSddsa.png), not to the JDK.